# How to create Angular 2 project using Backendless?

Tags: angular

I am new to using backendless and Angular 2 how can I start initial setup with a project.

Comment: Please see how to ask a good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

First You need node and npm to be installed in your pc
[Help Link](https://angular.io/guide/setup#install-prerequisites)

Then you can install angular-cli and create angular project or you can do as per [link](https://angular.io/guide/setup)

Answer (score 0):

You can go through [Angular.io][1],rather creating your srevices to call http requests you can manulate your data as you want from your component only.And all the datas will be static.
You can create a Hero project from [Angular.io][1].
I hope it will help you.
Things you need
1. Node.js
2. npm install -g @angular/cli
3. ng new my-app
4. cd my-app
5. ng serve --open
Now you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to setup project in Angular 2 Angular CLI will be good choice for you. So you have to open command prompt and go inside Your Drive , i will recommend you to go inside C: drive (root) and install angular globally.

```
c: > npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Wait for angular installation after that create angular project by below command

```
C: > ng new projectname
```

Wait for some time still project is not created.then move to that folder

```
C: > cd projectname
C: >projectname > ng serve
```

After ng serve it will some time to serve your web page on browser on 4200 port under development mode.

*Open browser (chrome) and put localhost:4200 inside url and hit enter and see the angular magic*

**Note: Please make sure node js is installed on your computer before doing above operation**

```
Cheers
```